# Remove sub-document from Mongo with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to remove an item from a collection that is stored in a mongoose document. My document looks like this:

```
{
  "__v": 3,
  "_id": "5221040475f174d59a000005",
  "items": [
    {
      "sku": 1321654654613213,
      "name": "goldfish",
      "quantity": 12,
      "_id": "52224ed5bd9d340000000003"
    },
    {
      "sku": 12,
      "name": "goldfish",
      "quantity": 13,
      "_id": "52225dcbf2f1e40000000003"
    },
    {
      "sku": 1299,
      "name": "goldfish",
      "quantity": 13,
      "_id": "522260b6f2f1e40000000004"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to remove the goldfish with the sku of 12. I am doing the following:

```
var inventory = res.locals.content;
inventory.items.remove( {sku: req.params.itemSku}, function (err, item) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('error occurred', err);
    res.send('error');
  }
  else {
    res.send('Item found and deleted');
    return; 
  }
});
```

when I do this, I get the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'equals' of undefined".  I don't understand why.

Comment: The word `equals` doesn't occur in the code you provided. Can you provide a stack trace perhaps?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You want `inventory.items.pull(req.params.itemSku)`, followed by an `inventory.save` call. `.remove` is for top-level documents

Comment: I'm not getting any errors when I use
    `inventory.items.pull({sku: req.params.itemSku});`
but that is returning the entire array instead of the element with the matching sku.  Why is that?

Comment: `pull` returns `this`, probably for chainability so you could do `inventory.items.pull(blah).push(blah)`. https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/c328227a21004c7c1a295d215bbe55801e29c9ea/lib/types/array.js#L470

Answer (score 32):

Subdocuments now have a [remove](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html#removing-subdocs) function. Use as follows from the spec:

```
var doc = parent.children.id(id).remove();
parent.save(function (err) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  console.log('the sub-doc was removed')
});
```

Comment: Is this an atomic call?

Comment: Actually, the actual save is atomic, I looked at the source and it looks like `remove()` uses `MongooseArray.pull` which, according to v4 docs: `Pulls items from the array atomically.` - in case you're worried about array indexes getting out of sync. That being said, you could also use `MongooseArray.pull` to do the same thing, just as the accepted answer states.

Comment: @OllyBarca I did indeed, hence "Use as follows from the spec".

Answer (score 13):

### Removing a subdocument from an array

The nicest and most complete solution I have found that both finds and removes a subdocument from an *array* is using Mongoose's [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) method:

```
Collection.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: yourCollectionId },
    { $pull: { subdocumentsArray: { _id: subdocumentId} } },
    { new: true },
    function(err) {
        if (err) { console.log(err) }
    }
)
```

The `{new: true}` ensures the updated version of the data is returned, rather than the old data.

Comment: {new: true} does not ensure existing document is overwritten. it only return result with updated data instead of old data in db. So its result where subdocument is removed.

Answer (score 7):

finaly!

```
MongoDB:

"imgs" : {"other" : [ {
        "crop" : "../uploads/584251f58148e3150fa5c1a7/photo_2016-11-09_21-38-55.jpg",
        "origin" : "../uploads/584251f58148e3150fa5c1a7/o-photo_2016-11-09_21-38-55.jpg",
        "_id" : ObjectId("58433bdcf75adf27cb1e8608")
                                    }
                            ]
                    },
router.get('/obj/:id',  function(req, res) {
var id = req.params.id;



Model.findOne({'imgs.other._id': id}, function (err, result) {
        result.imgs.other.id(id).remove();
        result.save();            
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#pull-array-of-documents) to remove a sub-document.

```
    Collection.update({
    _id: parentDocumentId
  }, {
    $pull: {
      subDocument: {
        _id: SubDocumentId
      }
    }
  });
```

This will find your parent document against given ID and then will remove the element from subDocument which matched the given criteria.

Comment: but for this I need to know both parent Id and subdocument Id which is not desired.

Answer (score 1):

```
    const deleteitem = (req, res) => {
    var id = req.body.id
    var iditem = req.body.iditem

    Venta.findOne({'_id': id}, function(err,result){
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);            
        }else{
            result.items.pull(iditem)
            result.save()
        }
    })}
module.exports = {deleteitem }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the parent's _id. You can just search for a parent which has a child with a specific id and pull that same child out with the following code:

```
const result = await User.updateOne(
  // Query the user collection for a document
  // with a child in it's accounts array with an _id of ChildAccountId.
  { 'accounts._id': 'ChildAccountId' },
  {
    // In the found parent document:
    $pull: { // pull something out of:
      accounts: { // the accounts array 
        _id: 'ChildAccountId' // which has has the _id of ChildAccountId.
      }
    }
  }
);
```

`result` in this case will have a response-object similar to the following one:

```
{
  acknowledged: true,
  modifiedCount: 1,
  upsertedId: null,
  upsertedCount: 0,
  matchedCount: 1
}
```

So you can easily check for the `result.modifiedCount` to see how many `SubDocuments` (in this case) were modified (where stuff got pulled out).

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE -**

*From mongoose 6.3.1 [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html#executing) -*

> When executing a query with a callback function, you specify your query as a JSON document. The JSON document's syntax is the same as the MongoDB shell.

.