# Mongoose .pull not deleting subdocument

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to remove a product from a category using mongoose .remove from these other questions but none seem to work

[Remove sub-document from Mongo with mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18553946/remove-sub-document-from-mongo-with-mongoose)

But nothing is happening and I only get back the same thing unedited

Category Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const Product = require('./Product');

const CategorySchema = Schema({
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  categoryName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  categoryDescription: String,
  productList: [Product],
});

mongoose.model('Category', CategorySchema);
```

Products Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ProductSchema = Schema({
  productName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  productDescription: String,
  categories: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category' },
});

mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);
```

My express route to handle deleting of the subdocument

```
app.delete('/api/category-with-product/:categoryId', (req, res) => {
    const categoryId = req.params.categoryId;
    const { productId } = req.body;

    Category.findById(categoryId)
      .then((category) => {
        category.productList.pull({ _id: productId });
        return category.save();
      })
      .then((newCategory) => {
        res.send(newCategory);
      });
  });
```

My expected outcome is for this is to just remove the product in the productList array

```
{
  _id: 5c5b990d56b3f61ce3736e6f,
  categoryName: 'A new category name',
  description: 'description',
  productList:[
     { _id: 5c6e4b5114333b25f8e9d737,
       productName: 'test',
       productDescription: 'test'
     } 
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this:

```
const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
function funcName() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      db.category.update(
           { },
           { $pull: { productList: { _id: ObjectId(productId) } } },
           { multi: true }
      )
        .then((result) => resolve())
        .catch((err) => reject(err));
    });
  }
```

You can also try Async/Await during database operations.

Comment: I'm now getting this error "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseError: Callback must be a function, got [object Object]" do you know how to solve?

Comment: The issue is with Callbacks. Try using promise or async/await to resolve the issue as updated in the answer.