# How to delete an nested object based on its ObjectId?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregate

I have this nested Schema for my **courses** collections, there is a **sessions** array in every course and a **students** array in every session  and every student is an object consisting of a property of userName with a value of ObjectId refering to my users collections and another property names status containing some number.

I want to delete an student object from my students array of my session with its _id.

I know it is possible to unwind arrray to get to a single object but I need a neat way like using an objectId to delete an object from database  so that we don't have to specify path like directly deleting or modifying that nested subdocument.

This is my course schema:

```
 CourseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
    sessions:[
        {
         date:Date,
         students :[{
             userName:{
                type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref :'users'
             },
             status:Number
         }]   
        }
    ]
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following DELETE route to delete a student from a course session.

```js
router.delete(
  "/course/:courseId/session/:sessionId/student/:studentId",
  async (req, res) => {
    try {
      let result = await Course.updateOne(
        { _id: req.params.courseId, "sessions._id": req.params.sessionId },
        {
          $pull: { "sessions.$.students": { userName: req.params.studentId } }
        }
      );

      res.send(result);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).send("Something went wrong");
    }
  }
);
```

Let's say you have a course like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5de907acdfcef9493cd215a8"),
    "name" : "Course 1",
    "sessions" : [
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2019-12-05T16:32:41.998+03:00"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5de907acdfcef9493cd215a9"),
            "students" : [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5de907acdfcef9493cd215ac"),
                    "userName" : ObjectId("5de8e4c8f74cf254d04f90d8"),
                    "status" : 1
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5de907acdfcef9493cd215ab"),
                    "userName" : ObjectId("5de8e4d5f74cf254d04f90d9"),
                    "status" : 1
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5de907acdfcef9493cd215aa"),
                    "userName" : ObjectId("5de8e4ddf74cf254d04f90da"),
                    "status" : 1
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

If we want to delete the student with userName with value `5de8e4ddf74cf254d04f90da`, we can send a DELETE request to our route using an url like this:

`http://localhost/courses/5de907acdfcef9493cd215a8/session/5de907acdfcef9493cd215a9/student/5de8e4ddf74cf254d04f90da`

5de907acdfcef9493cd215a8--> courseId

5de907acdfcef9493cd215a9--> sessionId

The response will be like this:

```
{
    "n": 1,
    "nModified": 1,
    "ok": 1
}
```

When we look at our course, we see the student is removed:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5de907acdfcef9493cd215a8"),
    "name" : "Course 1",
    "sessions" : [
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2019-12-05T16:32:41.998+03:00"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5de907acdfcef9493cd215a9"),
            "students" : [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5de907acdfcef9493cd215ac"),
                    "userName" : ObjectId("5de8e4c8f74cf254d04f90d8"),
                    "status" : 1
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5de907acdfcef9493cd215ab"),
                    "userName" : ObjectId("5de8e4d5f74cf254d04f90d9"),
                    "status" : 1
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

As we see the student with username with value `5de8e4ddf74cf254d04f90da` does not exists anymore in the course session, meaning it is removed.

Comment: tnx this probably helps but i was kinda hoping the would be some function that directly removes an obejction based on its uniq ObjectId  .... seems there is not

Comment: @Millw0 it would be possible if the session and students had their own seperate  collections. In your case they are embedded inside the course collection, so I don't think you can directly remove a student. But if I find anoher way, I will update the answer.

Comment: @Millw0  actually there seems to be another way, If I can make it work, I will update the answer.

Comment: @Millw0  I updated the answer, I think this is exactly what you wanted.

Comment: thnx @SuleymanSah the modified version is a more neat convenient way to do so .... but what i was seeking for at begining comes from some probably wronge perception of what mongo does .... since every single object in mongo has its own object ID i thought why shouldn't we be able to delete a subdocument only based on its objectID . i mean this objects are somewhere on memory so why can't mongo reach out for a subdocument based on just its object ID ... a way to circumvent querying from main document and directly accessing to every object embeded within a subdocument of document

Comment: @Millw0 I understood, this is a good question. Can you check this question?
Here he says the subdocuments have also remove method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23255415/11717458